# Updating declarative pipeline job's cron triggers doesn't update triggers

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I have a declarative pipeline job defined as a pipeline script (not pipeline from SCM). It has a cron trigger:

```
triggers {
    cron('H */4 * * 1-5')
}
```

I've run this a few times on-demand and cron triggered, and everything is fine so far. Now if I change the cron trigger, jenkins does not pick up the change, the old trigger is still in effect until I force a job run.

How do I get Jenkins to use the changed triggers without running the job manually? I think the question can be extended to any declarative job definition changes really, how do I get jenkins to update job settings without being forced to run the job.

Comment: did you tried to remove cron trigger from pipeline itself and use the one from Build Periodically section ?

Comment: @BigGinDaHouse That would work, but defeats the entire point of pipeline-as-code.

Comment: I know it is, but it is a least a solution for sitation, unless the proper one is found

Answer (score 4):

This is related to how Jenkins pipeline works. Triggering as well as other job configurations are only loaded into Jenkins itself only after the job is executed once. It is simply the egg and the chicken question.

Since a pipeline job should be in the context of the place that stored it (Github, for example), you should consider triggering it from there then use some internal logic to decide if to run it or not.

The complexity of this solution should be relative to the number of times you update your trigger.

Answer (score 1):

In short, currently, at time of writing, you can't.

I work around this for parameterised pipelines by adding a "noop" option and them making sure my pipeline does nothing when this option is selected.  That way the job runs but has no side effects.

If your pipeline is not parameterised we are currently, as I said, out of luck.

Comment: according to their docs it is possible - https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#triggers

Comment: Change that cron in the trigger and you will find that Jenkins will not pick the change in your schedule until it has run again.

Comment: exactly, that's the question, but if you ran once more it will pick it up and it is obvious that you have to run one time and still it does not mean that jenkins do not support it, but let's say supports with limitations

Comment: not what I was hoping to hear :( but thanks @AndrewGray